# In javascript how do I call a function dynamically added to an object

Tags: javascript

Keeping up with the Javascript learning effort. I am looking at the following code which aims to add functions to an object keeping them unique, something like adding callback functions to an event kind of thing.

```
var store = {
    nextId: 1,
    cache: {},
    add: function(fn) {
        if(!fn.id){
            fn.id = store.nextId++;
            return !!(store.cache[fn.id] = fn);
        }
    }
};
```

The code works well but now I would like to execute those functions and I haven't been able to figure that part out.

So far I have tried to call the two functions directly as methods of the store.cache object which gives me the error "Object# has no method 'blah'". Also I tried doing a loop as if store.cache was an array of functions but that didn't work either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The function can be invoked like so: `store.cache[1]()`, `store.cache[2]()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are easier ways to store a list of callbacks, but to solve your problem just do:

```
var i;
for (i in store.cache) {
    store.cache[i]();
}
```

for (i in variable) cycles through all the properties of variable, and i gets the key of the property.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to `store`, something like this

```
executeFunction: function(id) {
   var fn = store.cache[id];
   if (fn) return fn();
   else throw 'could not find function for id...';
}
```

and then you can just do

`var result = store.executeFunction(someId);`

you can expand upon that so that your `executeFunction` takes the context (scope) and arguments which should be applied to the function.